# json data is not displaying in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i'm trying to display data from url, it is in the form of json. my ajax code is as below

```
function loadMore(url) {
            alert(url);
             $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: url,
              data: data,
              success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    var table = document.getElementById("claimList");
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                        cell3.style.width = '25px';

                        // Add some text to the new cells:
                        cell1.innerHTML = '<td><a href="../institutedetails?businessId={{ data.businessId }}">{{ data.displayName }}</a></td>';
                        cell2.innerHTML = '<td>{{ data.businessAddress }}</td>';
                        cell3.innerHTML = '<td>{{ data.businessLocation }}</td>';
                    }


               },
              error: function (request, error) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    alert(" Can't load more because " + error);
                },
            });
        }
```

and html code is as follows

```
<div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter" id="claimList">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="header"> Institute Name <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
                                <th class="header"> Address <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
                                <th class="header"> Location <i class="icon-sort"></i></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for key in data %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="../institutedetails?businessId={{ key.businessId }}">{{ key.displayName }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ key.businessAddress }}</td>
                                <td>{{ key.businessLocation }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul class="pager">
                        <li class="next"><button class="btn btn-default" name="load_more" id="load_more" onclick="loadMore('{{ nextPage }}');">Load More</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

data is in the form of json and it is coming from url, but i don't know how to display the data via ajax

Comment: this does not show that `loadMore` is ever actually called.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea `loadMore` is called when the button is clicked

Comment: and you've verified this? and that the data is being received? (I see the `alert` in there)

Comment: that alert is also not working

Comment: which alert (there are two, one when the button is clicked, and one when the data should have been loaded)?

Comment: `alert(data); `

Comment: then ur problem is unrelated to "displaying the data" ... the data is never received. verify that your `$.ajax` implementation is working correctly (I would start with the fact that you are passing `data` to the call when it does not exist as a variable anywhere).

Comment: 'kay, but whats wrong in $.ajax

Comment: this is the part where you actually try to diagnose the issue and create a more clear problem definition. you have multiple issues related to your implementation, so try to do some more detailed analysis before requesting help.

Comment: Do you go in error? If your JSON is malformatted it won't go to success. Give it a try here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: loadMore('{{ nextPage }}'); check value here.